# YearWeek from DateTime

Tags: php, date, datetime

I would like to get YearWeek from DateTime in PHP:

```
$day = \DateTime ...
$YearWeek = date("YW", date_timestamp_get($day));
```

But in case the week is on two years, it does not work:

```
$day // 2017-01-01
$YearWeek // I get 201752 instead of 201652
```

What should I do?

Comment: Did you give up or what?!?!

Comment: No :). thank you for your reply

Answer (score 2):

From the manual for [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), use `o` instead of `Y`:

> ISO-8601 week-numbering year. This has the same value as Y, except
>   that if the ISO week number (W) belongs to the previous or next year,
>   that year is used instead. (added in PHP 5.1.0)

```
$day = strtotime('2017-01-01');
echo date("YW", $day);  //201752
echo date("oW", $day);  //201652
```