# date gives wrong year in combo year-week

Tags: php, date

I want to get the right year-week combo.
When i do this it gives me 2018-01, but it should be 2019-01.

`<?php
$today = date("2018-12-31 11:15:48");
echo date('Y-W', strtotime($today));
?>`

I can't be the first to encounter this, but i don't know how to search for this in the right way, because english is not my native language.

Comment: Found the answer! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41701989/yearweek-from-datetime Offcourse, after placing the question here...